# Customizing x-axis labels on plot

Tags: r, plot, axis

I plotted my data and also suppressed the auto x-axis labeling successfully.
Now I'm using the following command to customize my x=axis labels:

```
axis(
  1,
  at = min(LoopVariable[ ,"TW"]) - 1 : max(LoopVariable[ ,"TW"]) + 1,
  labels = min(LoopVariable[ ,"TW"]) - 1 : max(LoopVariable[ ,"TW"]) + 1,
  las = 2
)
```

And I'm getting:
[image]

This is correct in the sense that I'm having 28 data points, but when I do:

```
LoopVariable[ ,"TW"]
```

Then I get:

```
[1] 2801 2808 2813 2825 2833 2835 2839 2840 2844 2856 2858 2863 2865 2868 2870 2871 2873 2879 2881 2903 2904 2914 2918 2947 2970 2974 2977 2986
```

These are the the values I want as x-axis labels rather than 1:28. There is obviously a little bit missing in my line I seem not to figure out.

Comment: one thing is that you need to be careful with your brackets: `2 - 1:3 + 1` is not the same as `(2 - 1):(3 + 1)`

Comment: `@user20650` I changed my line to: `axis(1, at = (min(LoopVariable[ ,"TW"]) - 1) : (max(LoopVariable[ ,"TW"]) + 1), labels = (min(LoopVariable[ ,"TW"]) - 1) : (max(LoopVariable[ ,"TW"]) + 1), las = 2)` and now I do not get any x-axis labels.

Comment: hard to say without seeing your plot call... as in does the `at` align with your x values? But perhaps you just need `axis(1, at = seq(LoopVariable[ ,"TW"]), labels = LoopVariable[ ,"TW"])`

Comment: `@user20650` That has worked. Thank you very much!!